# Prestashop: show all attribute references of a product

Tags: php, html, css, prestashop

I added combinations in each product of my shop. This combination is 'packaging' and have 2 attributes: 100 units box and 200 units box. Each attribute have a reference number.

In product page, is showing a 'select' with this 2 attributes, and a text at right of this 'select' that updates with the reference number (if you select 100 units box, the text updates with de reference number of this attribute, and if you select 200 units box the reference number updates with other reference number, but NEVER you can see both reference number at the same).

What I want is show a list of this attributes and references instead a 'select', i need to display both attributes and references at the same time.

Now, this is my code (in product.tpl):

```html
<select style="float: left; margin-right: 15px; height: 23px; padding:0px; padding-bottom: 0px;" name="{$groupName}" id="group_{$id_attribute_group|intval}" class="form-control attribute_select no-print">
    {foreach from=$group.attributes key=id_attribute item=group_attribute}
        <option value="{$id_attribute|intval}"{if (isset($smarty.get.$groupName) && $smarty.get.$groupName|intval == $id_attribute) || $group.default == $id_attribute} selected="selected"{/if} title="{$group_attribute|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}">{$group_attribute|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}</option>
    {/foreach}supplier_reference
</select>
{if isset($FIELD_productShowReference) && $FIELD_productShowReference || !isset($FIELD_productShowReference)}
    <p style="padding-top: 3px;" id="product_reference"{if empty($product->reference) || !$product->reference} style="display: none;"{/if}>
            <label class="texto-referencia" style="float: left; font-size: 15px; margin-right: -5px;">{l s='Ref:'}</label>
            <span class="editable num-referencia" itemprop="sku" style="font-size: 15px;">{if !isset($groups)}{$product->reference|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}{/if}</span>
    </p>
{/if}
```

Comment: Sorry I dont´n know why my code above is not showing properly :S

Comment: What you could do is use a list of `<input type="radio" />` instead of a select, this way you'd be able to display both easily. But you'd have to modify the JS quite profusely.

Comment: Doing what you say I will have 2 radio buttons, but I still have only one text that displays the reference, this text will be update when I click the radio button. I dont want this, I want display both attributes and both references at the same. Thanks!

Comment: No. Your combinations of their own reference as you said, thus if you have them displayed alongside a radio button you'd be able to see the reference and the combination of the 2 attributes.

Comment: Well, then im gonna try, but I no have idea what do that, can u give me an example? :S

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
{foreach from=$group.attributes key=id_attribute item=group_attribute}
    <input type="radio" name="{$groupName}" value="{$id_attribute|intval}"{if (isset($smarty.get.$groupName) && $smarty.get.$groupName|intval == $id_attribute) || $group.default == $id_attribute} checked="checked"{/if}
{/foreach}

{if isset($FIELD_productShowReference) && $FIELD_productShowReference || !isset($FIELD_productShowReference)}
    <p style="padding-top: 3px;" id="product_reference"{if empty($product->reference) || !$product->reference} style="display: none;"{/if}>
            <label class="texto-referencia" style="float: left; font-size: 15px; margin-right: -5px;">{l s='Ref:'}</label>
            <span class="editable num-referencia" itemprop="sku" style="font-size: 15px;">{if !isset($groups)}{$product->reference|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}{/if}</span>
    </p>
{/if}
```

Comment: Voy a probar gracias ;) (veo que eres de barcelona por eso te contesto en castellano jeje)

Comment: Nada, no me carga ningun numero de referencia en el checkbox, me sale vacio :(

Comment: Corrijo, me salen los 2 checkbox con el mismo valor debajo (num. referencia), y aunque pinche en uno u otro, el valor no varia. De todos modos la idea es que se vean a la vez los dos numeros de referencia de los dos atributos. @joseantgv

Comment: Could you please upload a screenshot?

Comment: Please only use English for commenting. You're preventing other users to help you.